# jquery uploadify ie9 issue multipart not sent to server

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, uploadify

I am using jquery uploadify to upload images in my angular,Spring MVC based application.

Image upload works perfect in all browsers except IE9.

In case of IE 9 i get following error at server

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
```

But the same code snippet works prefectly fine in other browsers and also in IE 10.

Can anyone please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/uploadHandler.js"></script>
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.Jcrop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
```

I missed few javascript files earlier, which was causing an issue, it is resolved now after including all above files